# Flash raises but the camera thinks it doesn't

Tags: canon, equipment-damage, popup-flash

On my Canon EOS Rebel T2i, in automatic mode in low light, the flash raises as expected.  However, after the flash raises, I continue to hear the clicking of the flash raise mechanism, and then I see the following message:

> Err 05
>
> The built-in flash could not be raised.
>
> Turn the camera off and on again.

I cannot take any pictures with it in this state.  Of course, I have tried tuning it off and back on.  It seems that the mechanism that detects that the flash is up is malfunctioning.  Is this something I can clear myself (maybe by blowing compressed air or something? Or resetting something in the settings?)  I don't see anything in the flash area that is obviously a problem.  Or should I just take it in for service?

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: A couple of wild guesses here: 1) If you have compressed air at hand, you could give it a try and let us know; I guess it's very unlikely that you'll damage it. 2) By the sound of it I'd guess service could have it done from one day to the next.

Comment: Have you checked that the microswitch on the hotshoe that detects an external flash is mounted isn't jammed? See [this POTN post](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?p=15624758).

Comment: Thanks @Roflo, the compressed air didn't help. I took it in to a local camera shop, since I called Canon, and they told me it would be $190 minimum do do anything... hopefully the local guys can do it cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @inkista, but I don't think that was it, since I did hear the clicking (repeatedly, actually), and the flash did pop up-- the problem seems to be in the mechanism that tells the camera that it popped up.

Comment: Ah, well. Good luck then. Do post an answer when you know what the issue was.

Comment: *I cannot take any pictures with it in this state.* - I haven't used the flash in years.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem after the external flash is detached from my canon camera(T5i). The problem solved after i turned the camera off and on again. 
I think this is the problem in the software driver. Have you tried resetting all the settings or factory reset? If not try it, it should work.